# Translate ONLY italian text, inside LaTeX sources, into english

Tags: conversion, languages

I want to translate my LaTeX italian sources into english, using e.g. "google translate".
I must "extract" italian text, leaving LaTeX keywords and formulas unchanged.

Example:

```
\section{Introduzione}

\newcommand{\erelmax}{10^{-3}}
\EXE{Calcolare con uno scarto relativo minore o uguale a $\erelmax$
i valori $\xi$ t.c.
\beq
  \sin(\xi) = \cos(\xi) % \label{eq:ln=cos}
\eeq
} % end EXE
```

Should be converted into:

```
\section{Introduction}

\newcommand{\erelmax}{10^{-3}}
\EXE{Compute with a relative gap less than or equal to $\erelmax$
the values $\xi$ s.t.
\beq
  \sin(\xi) = \cos(\xi) % \label{eq:ln=cos}
\eeq
} % end EXE
```

Any hint?

Comment: Ciao Flavio! The question might be interesting, but has nothing to do with TeX and LaTeX, I'm afraid.

Comment: unless any of the macro names happen to be italian words, google translate should just ignore them, shouldn't it?

Comment: Compile it to a PDF and use `pdftotext` to get it as text version which can be used for translation. You will still have some other things in it I'm afraid. You could ignored these using the `comment` package or `\long\def\beq#1\eeq{}` etc. If you however want to extract and then automatically reinsert the translation then you are out of luck I think.

Comment: @Martin: Wouldn't `detex` be easier, if the purpose is to extract text?

Comment: @You: Oh, I assume so. I didn't remember that one.