# How can I translate to English a TeX document without losing compilability?

Tags: languages

Is there any way I can translate comments and non-commands from a different language to English ?

I tried :

1. Google Search

   - https://www.google.lk/#q=translate+a+latex+code+without+losing+content
   - https://www.google.lk/#q=translate+a+german+latex+to+english

   No results
2. Using http://translate.google.com/ to translate File pasted as text

   File : http://phobos.xtec.cat/jqueralt/IMG/tex/packtpub.tex

   Obviously will not compile
3. Using http://translate.google.com/ to translate File drag-and-drop

   I got the following result:

   > Sorry, the page you requested contains a file type (application/octet-stream) we are unable to translate.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Hi! A similar question has appeared before: [Translate ONLY italian text, inside LaTeX sources, into english](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23821). It was conlcuded that this type of question is off-topic. I'm not claiming that this question should be consider off-topic; I'm just putting here the relevant information.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look on http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/online.php . This tools has algorithms to find "real text" and comments in your TeX code. Haven't looked on the source code, but maybe there is some nice code to extract your text for translation. (Just an idea for hacking that...)

Comment: detex strips out a lot of commands etc. but it probably still leaves maths. It might be a good start, though.

Comment: a solution could be with regular expression and e.g. perl, so you parse for comments (easy) and other text (more difficult?), remember the position of the single pieces of text in the whole file and write  the text linewise in a file. Translate that file. Read it in again and put the text back in the document at stored places.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

1. Save the file with a `.txt` extension. This will avoid the error "Sorry, the page you requested contains a file type (application/octet-stream) we are unable to translate."
2. Change all backslashes using your editor to `==zz`. This results to words that Google cannot translate and hence it leaves as is. This works well for single commands.

Use the same strategy for any other items you do not want Google to translate. For example you can search and replace all `{` with `BACKSLASHSH`. This way you will not get any unwanted spaces. Just use words or mixtures of words and numbers that Google will not have a translation. For example it will translate `figure` but not `FIGORE`.

3. Translate text.
4. Search and replace again with your editor all `==zz` to backslashes and other strings you have protected.

If you familiar with coding in a language such as Perl, Python or Lua you can fence the commands in a more robust way, by providing a small script to do all the search and replace.
For example you could change all:

```
   \begin{figure}[htbp]
```

to a hash key such as `12345678` to protect it from translation, and then reverse it back again once you have the translation.

Sadly Google does not provide a free web API any longer, otherwise you could have done all this automatically via LuaTeX and the socket library or similar.

Answer (score 6):

You can use https://www.deepl.com
You can give it tex file. DeepL keeps formating and markup (although, not always).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a tool [`gtexfix`](https://github.com/drgulevich/gtexfix) which I wrote which does the replacements of LaTeX commands and math formulas by tokens automatically. It helps to translate safely `.tex` documents with Google Translate without breaking the LaTeX.